# How do I convert mongoDB array query to PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Hey guys so I'm now starting to learn mongo and PHP at the same time. Are there any resources online that can point me in the right direction on how to convert mongo commands so that PHP can understand it?
For example I am using the 'find' command to find all documents in a collection that have an array field name 'vendor' with criteria in its specific position.
An example if what I mean is that I want to be able to specify which array position to look into to see if the criteria is there

A small snippet of What I have is :

```
require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";              

$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->POS->Product;

 

 

$vendorname = $ProdVen['vendor'];

                $position = $ProdVen['position'];

                $page = isset($ProdVen['page']) ? (int)$ProdVen['page'] : 1;

                $limit = (int)$ProdVen['limit'];

                $skip = ($page - 1) * $limit; //amount of documents to skip

 

$result = $collection->find(['vendor->$position' => $vendorname],['limit' => $limit, 'skip' => $skip]);
```

Do I have the correct syntax where I have

```
find(['vendor->$position' => ....
```

I understand that the normal syntax for mongodb would be

```
find({"vendor.1":.....
```

Thankyou !

Comment: Can you show how you've constructed ```vendor``` and add what error you're getting with the syntax you're using?

Comment: 'vendors' is just an array in mongo of an unspecified number of elements. I just want the correct syntax to use so I can plug in any index number via a variable in php and get the results from that index number. Im not getting any errors when I run in the console, just no output.